# How to write a rhumb line bearing?

Tags: symbology, bearing

I am working with an American translation (1922) of the logs of Vitus Bering's voyages in the North Pacific Ocean (1742).

Latitude and longitude are written in the format **52° 02′ N** and **1° 57′ E**, but the rhumb lines are written in the format **S54°21′E**.

Are there spaces missing from the rhumbs or is this how they should be written? Why is there a cardinal direction at both the start and end of the rhumb?

Comment: From the location described as 52° 02′ N and 1° 57′   facing due south.  Then rotate 54°21′  towards the east.   Head in that direction.